# Missing call to bound pointer to member function

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers, c++11

I am trying to implement a generic event handling system with templates, but I get an error at compile time when I try to add the function to a list.

> error C2298: missing call to bound pointer to member function

```
class EventManager
{
public:
    template <class OBJECT>
    void subscribe(std::string eventName, OBJECT *obj, void(OBJECT::*newEvent)(Event))
    {
        (obj->*newEvent)(Event()); // I can call the event just fine if I execute it alone
        abc.push_back(obj->*newEvent); // Error c2298 here
    }

    static EventManager* Get();

private:
    std::vector<void(*)(Event)> eventsList;
};
```

And this is where I call it:

```
EventManager::Get()->subscribe("EventName", this, &TestClass::eventTest);

void ATideManager::eventTest(Event event)
{
    //Test
}
```

I am quite new to C++ and templates, so I'm sure the solution is easy, but I don't understand why I can call the event but not add it to the vector. Do you know how I could possibly do that?

Comment: Can you please add `TestClass` into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation for that error message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcy3ee2.aspx) says:

> A pointer to member-function expression must call the member function.

In other words, you cannot store a pointer to member-function including the object on which to call it, for later use.

Here is a simpler example using names similar to yours:

```
struct Object
{
    void f() {}
};

int main()
{
    Object obj;

    using member_function_pointer = void (Object::*)(); 

    member_function_pointer ptr = &Object::f;

    (obj.*ptr)();
    (obj.*ptr); // error
}
```

And this makes a lot of sense. Your `abc` is probably a vector of pointers to member-function (or just a vector of function pointers); it cannot magically store an object along with each pointer in it.

Generally, pointers to member functions are not exactly the nicest, cleanest or best feature of C++, and the awful syntax renders every piece of code using it completely unreadable. Fortunately, C++11 introduced **`std::function` and lambdas**, which gives you a much better alternative:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Event
{
    int i;
};

class EventManager
{
public:
    void subscribe(std::string const& eventName,
                   std::function<void(Event const&)> event)
    {
        abc.push_back(event);
    }

    static EventManager& get()
    {
        static EventManager instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void onEvent(Event const& event)
    {
        for (auto&& f : abc)
        {
            f(event);
        }
    }

private:
    EventManager() {}
    EventManager(EventManager const&) = delete;
    EventManager& operator=(EventManager const&) = delete;

    std::vector<std::function<void(Event const&)>> abc;

};

struct ATideManager
{
    void f()
    {
        EventManager::get().subscribe("EventName",
            [=](Event const& event) { eventTest(event); });
    }

    void eventTest(Event const& event)
    {
        std::cout << "eventTest: " << event.i << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    ATideManager manager;
    manager.f();
    Event some_event{ 123 };
    EventManager::get().onEvent(some_event);
}
```

I've also fixed your needless use of pointers where references can be used, and some `const`-correctness issues.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`obj->*newEvent` is invalid. A member function pointer can be used in this way only to call the pointed-to member function.

You can however use `std::vector<std::function<void(Event)>>` and

```
abc.push_back(std::bind(newEvent, obj, std::placeholders::_1);
```

[`std::bind` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)